# Not null on both sides of One-to-many in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, erd, cardinality

How are one-to-many relationships implemented? It is often recommended to do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE instructor (
  instructor_id integer primary key,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE course (
  course_id integer primary key,
  instructor_id integer not null references instructor(instructor_id),
  ...
);
```

While this guarantees that the course will have a instructor, it doesn't guarantee the instructor will have a course. I see drawings with business rules as in this page where it is supposedly possible:
[http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~bernatja/crowsfoot.html](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Ebernatja/crowsfoot.html)

I am trying to make an implementation of b9 on that page, where instructors must have 1 or more courses and the course must be taught by one instructor. I've tried adding a not null foreign key to the instructor table along with deferred foreign keys to get around insert issues but the instructor_id in the course table is not a unique index, so that doesn't work. How can I guarantee that my instructor has a course?

Comment: While it might be possible in an entitity-relationship-diagram to have 1…N cardinality, there is no direct equivalent in an SQL database schema. One could achieve a lot with triggers, but this is usually not done.

Comment: In theory, this is what the `ASSERTION` is for in the SQL standard. But in reality, no database supports them though.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not possible as you will need at some point to insert a new instructor or a course.  If it's a new instructor, no course can reference it beforehand and thus you'll have an instructor without a course - and vice versa.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Things like these are possible with deferred constraints that are only checked when the transaction is committed, but yeah the chicken-egg-problem makes this quite complicated.